# VisualStudio - How to escape this chars

Tags: visual-studio, escaping, character, special-characters, unicode-escapes

I think i need to escape the special chars here:

```
Process.Start(userSelectedFilePath, "\u0007" & ThisDir.Path & "\u000B" & checkedpath1 & "\u0007")
```

The result need to be like: userselecfilepath "a blackquoted path\and other folder"

what i'm doing wrong?

thankyou

**UPDATE**

Solution:

```
ControlChars.Quote & Path.Combine(ThisDir.Path, checkedpath1) & ControlChars.Quote
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Process.Start(userSelectedFilePath, Path.Combine(ThisDir.Path, checkedpath));
```

**[Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)**

> If path1 is not a drive reference (that is, "C:" or "D:") and does not
>   end with a valid separator character as defined in
>   DirectorySeparatorChar, AltDirectorySeparatorChar, or
>   VolumeSeparatorChar, DirectorySeparatorChar is appended to path1
>   before concatenation.
>
> If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start
>   with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a
>   concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator
>   character. If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.
>
> The parameters are not parsed if they have white space. Therefore, if
>   path2 includes white space (for example, " c:\ "), the Combine method
>   appends path2 to path1 instead of returning only path2.
>
> Not all invalid characters for directory and file names are
>   interpreted as unacceptable by the Combine method, because you can use
>   these characters for search wildcard characters. For example, while
>   Path.Combine("c:\", "*.txt") might be invalid if you were to create a
>   file from it, it is valid as a search string. It is therefore
>   successfully interpreted by the Combine method.

Comment: it says i don't have "Path" declared, what i need to do? anyway I need to put a slash between "ThisDir.Path \ checkedpath", not combine, so i think your example don't works for me... maybe i'm worng, thankyou

Comment: make sure you reference `System.IO`. `Path.Combine` will add in the `/`

Comment: thank again, my final solution was: ControlChars.Quote & Path.Combine(ThisDir.Path, checkedpath1) & ControlChars.Quote

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Process.Start(userSelectedFilePath, "\\" & ThisDir.Path & "\\" & checkedpath1 & "\\")